# Missing standard C libraries in cl

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nmake

I have a Windows project that came with a Makefile.vc. I would like to import this into Visual Studio 10.0. My initial effort is to run nmake and invoke the cl.exe compiler.

After getting some paths straights my first run generates this message:

```
        cl  /nologo /W3 /O1 -I..\./ -I..\charset/ -I..\windows/ -I..\unix/ -I..\macosx/ /D_WINDOWS /D_WIN32_WINDOWS=0x500 /DWINVER=0x500 /DHAS_GSSAPI /DSECURITY
_WIN32  /c ..\be_all_s.c
be_all_s.c
..\be_all_s.c(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Now I know where the VC stdio.h header is, on my PC it's at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include. So it would be a simple matter to add a -I to the makefile and include this directory.

But durn burn it I don't think I should have to! Other build systems don't make me do this and why doesn't the command line compiler know where its standard headers are installed? So I'm asking if there's a config file, an .ini file or something else that cl reads that tells it where to look for the standard C library. I've been browsing the internet and Visual Studio help with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Just after I posted the question I found the answer.

Start > All Programs > Microsoft Visual 10.0 > Microsoft Visual Studio Tools > Visual Studio Command Prompt

This gives me a command prompt with all the paths, env. variables etc. set.

Why didn't I find that earlier?